# Can we control the retry limit and frequency of outbound messages

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

Outbound messages when error out will be retried for next 24 hours in an exponential manner. is there any way to configure this retry and reduce the frequency?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly on this . But what can be done is by comparing the created time and last modified time you can change the status of OBM object and stop it from retrying .

Give it a try